# Azure AD b2c remove Change Password step in Password Reset

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

During the password reset policy, you enter an email and verify it by entering a code emailed to the account you enter.  Once you hit continue, you are given the options to: 'Change Email', 'Continue', or 'Cancel'.

Is there any way to skip this step?  It's really not necessary and probably only adds confusion.  'Cancel' is available throughout the whole process and 'Change Email' serves nearly the same purpose.  It seems very unlikely to be used once you've already gone through the effort of verifying your email anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot currently change the flow of the Password Reset Policy for Azure AD B2C.

This is a kind of MFA step for [SSPR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr).

You can upvote this UserVoice feedback item: ["Change password" policy](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334326--change-password-policy). Azure Team has already followed it. You can also give your comments on that page.

Hope this helps!